# Tracing an outline using Qt Graphics

Tags: c++, qt, vector-graphics

I'm creating a comic book editor. I want to be able to use some fairly complex customisable shapes for the speech balloons.

I can draw the tail and then draw a balloon but that means I have the outline inside the shape and I want it only around the edge.

I assumed `QPainterPath::simplified()` would solve the problem but it doesn't seem to do anything.

At the moment my best idea is to draw a shape with a thick outline and then draw it again with no outline but I don't think that will work for "zero width" outlines.

Comment: So you're drawing a speech balloon as two shapes? One for the balloon itself, and one for the tail? Why not simply draw both of them together as a single path?

Comment: Because I want to be able to draw the tail as a curve, and position the balloon (which may be an ellipse, square, jagged edge or any other subclass of my basic balloon class) at an arbitrary point. Finding a consistent method to represent the balloon turns out to be difficult. If I could just draw the curve then an ellipse then that would be easier

Comment: I'm not familiar with `QPainterPath` myself, but I know that similar graphics APIs (such as the [Cairo](http://cairographics.org) library) often allow you to have "sub-paths" - perhaps you could draw the tail and the main balloon as two closed sub-paths within a single "container" path? If this isn't possible, try the second of the two options I have suggested below.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two possible solutions here:

- **Draw both the "tail" and the main "balloon" as a single shape.** In this case, you'd simply draw a single shape with a single outline and a single fill.
- **Draw them separately, but twice**. Draw an "expanded" version of the shapes in black first, and then draw the "normal" version of the shapes in white over the top of it. You wouldn't draw any "lines" at all - the "expanded" version of the fill would serve the same purpose.

The first method would allow alternative line styles to be used (dotted or wiggly lines), but the latter would allow the "outline" to be slightly offset, so that it appeared thicker around some edges and thinner around others.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out `QPainterPath::simplified()` does work. It depends on whether I draw clockwise or anti-clockwise  (I believe it works when drawn clockwise), which I presume is down to how Qt's Winding Fill works.

```
// create a path representing the bubble and its "tail"
QPainterPath tail = tail.shape();
tail.addPath(bubble.shape());
tail.setFillRule(Qt::WindingFill);

painter->drawPath(tail.simplified);
```